# If you have a quadratic where "a" and "b" values are given, how do you find the values of c so that the quadratic intersects with its inverse?

Tags: functions, quadratics, inverse-function

I have a question where it is asking to find the values of a for which the graph of $f(x) = x^2 + 2x + a$ will intersect with its inverse. I solved it to the point where $a = -x(x-3)$, but how do you solve for $a$?

Comment: My suggestion is not entirely mathematical. The graphs of y = f(x) and y = $f^{-1}(x)$ are symmatrical about the line $y = x$. One trivial solution is when a = 0, both $y = f(x) = x^2 + 2x$ and $y = x$ will pass through (0, 0). In that case, $y = f^{-1}(x)$ should also pass through (0, 0).

Answer (score 1):

So $f(x) = x^2+2x+a = (x+1)^2+(a-1)$ and to find the inverse, we have
$$
\begin{split}
x &= (y+1)^2+(a-1) \\
(y+1)^2 &= x-a+1 \\
y &= -1 \pm \sqrt{x-a+1}
\end{split}
$$
Thus, $f^{-1}(x) = -1 \pm \sqrt{x-a+1}$.

Where will $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ intersect?